Why does using the ground on an open collector module break my circuit?
I am using an open collector (OC1) by diligent to ultimately drive a stepper but first I am troubleshooting with an LED. I am confused on the wiring. I am using a beaglelbone black to generate my square wave to the OC1. I have my code working as I tested it by hooking up my breadboard directly to the pins. When I try to use the OC1 something breaks, which I cannot seem to figure out. I did stumble on a wiring that did work but I am not sure why.
I am hoping someone could walk me through this gap in understanding. I have provided of the working and not working schematic below.
I think the issue is me connecting the GND pins on both sides but since I am ultimately working my way to the GND pin on the beaglebone I am not sure why it makes a difference. An explanation of what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance


"The PmodOC1 utilizes MMBT3904 transistors in an open collector format. Each transistor can drive up to 100 mA of current individually and can draw up to 200 mA of current."  huh WTF? that doesn't make any sense

This is how you are meant to use it.

The light should be much brighter with this wiring.
inside there are 4 repeats of this

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
if you leave GND unconnected then no current will flow therough the emitter of the transistor and it will come out of the collector instead, which is how the "working" circuit operates.

Thanks for this answer. Just to clarify my understanding ... The square wave signal controls the LED by raising and lower the potential after current has moved through the LED? I ask because I will move this to a stepper controller and the VCC will always show high so I am not sure how the pulses are generated in the corrected circuit.

the driver turns high puses into low pulses,  for the stepper you connect the common to the VCC (or some other positive DC voltage)  and connect the indidual phases to the outs.

Ok last question, I do not how it can operate multiple signals when they all are connected to the common Vcc. My stepper has separate signal for CW and CCW directions. So the Vcc will go to V+ for both directions and the V- for each will go to the 1 of the 4 channels. I guess I am confused on how the VCC which is constant??? gets manipulated when the input signal is going into V- for two signals at once.

if you already have a stepper controller you probably do not need the module.

Point taken but still curious how this module can create 4 different pulse trains if the output is the Vcc. That is why I had it wired backward in the first place. I do not understand how multiple signals can be managed with the signal connected to the outs.

the output is the output , the output pulses are seen between VCC and the output pins.   the direction that the current flows is not significant.

I don't see how your "working" circuit is working - it must be torturing the transistors in the OC1.
The GND terminal of the OC1 must be connected to the power supply Ground, and the anode of the LED connected to +3.3 V through a resistor to control the LED current.  The transistor in the OC1 will ground its output when the input signal is High, and will act as an open circuit when the input signal is Low..

Thanks for this.... I am not sure how it worked either but this was driving a stepper for while but it might explain why it suddenly stopped working =). Is there an advantage of using the open collector? I think what through me off is having my square wave on the lower potential side of the LED.
